# select data based on datetime in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to create some sort of "functional select" that gives users flexibility to create configuration to select data in pandas dataframes. However I ran into some issues that puzzle me.

The following is a simplified example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', periods=4), 'val': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
>>> df
        date  val
0 2020-01-01    1
1 2020-01-02    2
2 2020-01-03    3
3 2020-01-04    4
```

Question 1:
Why do I get different result when I apply the function on the column differently?

```
>>> import datetime
>>> bydatetime = lambda x : x == datetime.date(2020, 1, 1)
>>> bydatetime(df['date'])
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
Name: date, dtype: bool
>>> df['date'].apply(bydatetime) # why does this one work?
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
Name: date, dtype: bool
```

However if I use numpy's `datetime64` or pandas' `Timestamp` types to create the lambda function, it would work.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> bynpdatetime = lambda x : x == np.datetime64('2020-01-01')
>>> bynpdatetime(df['date'])
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
Name: date, dtype: bool
>>> df['date'].apply(bynpdatetime)
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
Name: date, dtype: bool
>>> bypdtimestamp = lambda x : x == pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01')
>>> bypdtimestamp(df['date'])
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
Name: date, dtype: bool
>>> df['date'].apply(bypdtimestamp)
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
Name: date, dtype: bool
```

So I reverted to use the following simple selection, and using `datetime.date` didn't work. If `datetime.date` just wouldn't work, why would `df['date'].apply(bydatetime)` work?

```
>>> df[df['date'] == datetime.date(2020, 1, 1)]
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [date, val]
Index: []
>>> df[df['date'] == np.datetime64('2020-01-01')]
        date  val
0 2020-01-01    1
>>> df[df['date'] == pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01')]
        date  val
0 2020-01-01    1
```

Last but not least, why is the type of the `date` column `datetime64` in the DataFrame but `Timestamp` when selected one cell? What is exactly the difference between them?

```
>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------  --------------  -----         
 0   date    4 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 1   val     4 non-null      int64         
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(1)
memory usage: 192.0 bytes
>>>
>>> df['date'][0]
Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00')
```

I am sure there is something fundamental that I don't understand here. Thank you very much for anything constructive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luckily I have an older version of `pandas` (0.25) and you get a warning when you do `bynpdatetime(df['date'])`, which explains exactly why you see that behavior. [There was a bit of back and forth on how to handle this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.23.1.html#fixed-regressions) so seeing this behavior will be highly version specific:

> FutureWarning: Comparing Series of datetimes with 'datetime.date'. 
>   Currently, the 'datetime.date' is coerced to a datetime. In the future
>   **pandas will not coerce, and 'the values will not compare equal to the
>   'datetime.date'.** To retain the current behavior, convert the
>   'datetime.date' to a datetime with 'pd.Timestamp'.

[Datetime functionality in `pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html) is built upon the `np.datetime64` and `np.timedelta64` dtypes. **You should not use the datetime module** as they have made certain choices that are inconsistent with the standard library. All of the unintended behavior is because of this.

---

To answer the other un-related question. `datetime64` is like the array-type, or the concept. That array (in this case a `pd.Series`) would be made up of scalar `timedelta64` objects. This is explained in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#overview)

Comment: @SergeBallesta It's definitely one of the biggest hurdles when starting out with pandas, I wish they'd make it more explicit and perhaps add warnings about working with `datetime` objects. Mostly these things crop up with timezones, but the list continues to get longer with updates like this.