# Pandas distinguish between "date" and "string" columns both with "object" type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, validation, datetime

This seems like a straightforward question, but I've been stuck for a while on it now. Apologies if this has been asked already. I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
zed = pd.DataFrame({'gameDate': {0: datetime.date(2019, 12, 12),
  1: datetime.date(2019, 12, 12),
  2: datetime.date(2019, 12, 12),
  3: datetime.date(2019, 12, 12),
  4: datetime.date(2019, 12, 12)},
 'periodType': {0: 'REGULAR',
  1: 'REGULAR',
  2: 'REGULAR',
  3: 'REGULAR',
  4: 'REGULAR'}})
```

and when I check to see the `dtypes` of this dataframe, I get the following output:

```
print(zed.dtypes)

gameDate      object
periodType    object
dtype: object
```

How can the `date` types be distinguished from the `string` types when both are returned as `object`? I have a much larger dataframe for which I need to identify all columns of type `date` (not `datetime` or `timestamp`, but specifically `date` only, like above), but I don't specifically know the column names. I'd like to use something like the `.dtypes` function to help reveal these columns.

I could create a function that tests if the string is of the format `yyyy-mm-dd`, but that seems tedious.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to keep the `datetime.date`? `pandas` is compatible with the `np.datetime64[ns]` and `np.timedelta64[ns]` dtypes. Because the datetime module is not the supported library there are several issues that you can encounter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60888277/select-data-based-on-datetime-in-pandas-dataframe/60888432#60888432 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60256108/datetime-timestamp-returns-different-values-in-pandas-apply-and-dataframe-select/60256274#60256274 are two examples where pandas diverges from the standard datetime module.

Comment: The real data is fetched from a SQL database into python. It is a `date` type in the database, and it seems looks like python / pandas is simply auto-casting the column into `datetime.date`.

Comment: I'd append to my question then "how can i cast into `np.datetime64[ns]`", but this can be looked up easily

Comment: Missing values might complicate this, but you could check the first value of each column: `zed.iloc[0].apply(type)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1- Use pd.datetime in the construction of your 'gameDate' dictionary as follow:

```
zed = pd.DataFrame(
    {'gameDate': {
        0: pd.datetime(2019, 12, 12),
        1: pd.datetime (2019, 12, 12),
        2: pd.datetime(2019, 12, 12),
        3: pd.datetime(2019, 12, 12),
        4: pd.datetime(2019, 12, 12)
    },
     'periodType': {
         0: 'REGULAR',
         1: 'REGULAR',
         2: 'REGULAR',
         3: 'REGULAR',
         4: 'REGULAR'
     }
    }
)
```

- but **pd.datetime** is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in the future.

2- Convert the column after declaring the dataframe (probably the best practice). Just use:

```
zed = pd.DataFrame(
    {'gameDate': {
        0: datetime.date(2019, 12, 12),
        1: datetime.date(2019, 12, 12),
        2: datetime.date(2019, 12, 12),
        3: datetime.date(2019, 12, 12),
        4: datetime.date(2019, 12, 12)
    },
    'periodType': {
        0: 'REGULAR',
        1: 'REGULAR',
        2: 'REGULAR',
        3: 'REGULAR',
        4: 'REGULAR'
    }
   }
)

zed['gameDate'] = pd.to_datetime(zed['gameDate'])
```